# Meaning of term "differentiably closed"

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am reading Differential Topology by C. T. C. Wall. In the first chapter, he defines a smooth manifold. Without going into too much detail, he defines a smooth $m$ manifold $M^m$ as a Hausdorff space with a family $\mathcal{F}$ of continuous real valued functions defined on $M$. One of the conditions for a manifold to be smooth is that the family $\mathcal{F}$ is "differentiably closed", that is for each smooth function $F$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and any collection $f_1,\ldots,f_k\in\mathcal{F}$, we have $F(f_1,\ldots,f_k)\in\mathcal{F}$. It appears to me that we should have $n=k$ but this condition is not stated in the text. Should this condition have been included or does it make sense without the relation on $n$ and $k$?

Comment: $F(f_1, \dots f_k)$ doesn't make sense unless $n = k$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yeah, I thought so. I'll have to contact the author and let them know.